# Usage of token storage with JWT

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, silex

I have an API app which is now being refactored for supporting JWT-based authentication. After short investigation regarding the ways the authentication provider can be implemented I [this solution](https://github.com/cnam/security-jwt-service-provider/).

But what is interesting to me is that it stores the token in `TokenStorage` instance which implements the `TokenStorageInterface`. Since `TokenStorageInterface.getToken()` has no incoming params, I wonder how app knows that the retrieved token is really from the current user (if we are talking about RESTful service, which should be stateless)?

UPD: I was thinking about storing decoded valid token/User in `Request.attributes` collection, so `Request.get('currentUser')` will always returns the valid current user. What do you think about this approach? This way no token storage is involved so I can be sure token is not stored somewhere at server-side...

Comment: Instead of trying to invent your own solution try something like JWT with Guad in Symfony > 2.7: http://de.slideshare.net/weaverryan/symfony-guard-authentication-fun-with-api-token-social-login-jwt-and-more - why should you change some standard behaviour here?

Comment: @LBA Thanks, I guess that's what I was looking for